# Cannot set property 'pur' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, bluebird

I'm using angular with bluebird and [angular-bluebird-promises](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bluebird-promises) to override the built in Angular promise.
After upgrading to angular v1.6.5 when calling $interval.cancel an exception accrues. I have checked earlier version of angular and the following code was added:

```
function markQStateExceptionHandled(state) {
  state.pur = true;
}
function markQExceptionHandled(q) {
  markQStateExceptionHandled(q.$$state);
}
```

the problem is that bluebird promise does not have  $$state attribute and an exception is thrown:

```
> TypeError: Cannot set property 'pur' of undefined
>         at markQStateExceptionHandled (angular.js?3437:17654)
>         at markQExceptionHandled (angular.js?3437:17657)
>         at Function.interval.cancel (angular.js?3437:13650)
>         at eval (ng-infinite-scroll.js?6418:180)
>         at callback (angular.js?3437:13629)
>         at Scope.$digest (angular.js?3437:18515)
>         at Scope.$apply (angular.js?3437:18903)
>         at tick (angular.js?3437:13619)
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the above code is - but as a temp hack you can do `Promise.prototype.$$state = {}` which bluebird would be ok with

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug in Angular.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/16164). There is a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/16471) to fix it by changing the code to check there's `$$state`:

```
function markQStateExceptionHandled(state) {
  if (state) {
    state.pur = true;
  }
}
```

It's due 1.6.10. In the meantime you can fix it from Bluebird's side by doing:

```
Promise.prototype.$$state = {};
```

I can promise it won't mess anything from the bluebird side and won't have too many downsides other than being an ugly hack.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. When adding this line unhandledrejection event fires. I guess it is for the canceled promise